# Prove that $2^k + 1$ is only a perfect square for $k = 3$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

As the title shows I'm trying to prove for $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$ that $2^k + 1$ is only a perfect square when $k = 3$. My apologies if this question is a duplicate.

My progress so far:

> Suppose that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}^+$ such that $2^k + 1 = n^2$.  Then we have $2^k = n^2 - 1 = (n - 1)(n + 1)$.
>
> It is easy to see that for $k = 1, 2$ there are no solutions, while for $k = 3$ there is.
>
> Now suppose that $k > 3$. Then $16 \mid 2^k$, so we must also have $16 \mid (n - 1)(n + 1)$.

Now I think I can somehow derive a contradiction by using the fact that exactly one of $n - 1, n+1$ is divisible by $4$, but I don't know how.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: See also (for general interest) [Can consecutive integers be perfect powers?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610131/can-consecutive-integers-be-perfect-powers)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can you see that $(n-1)(n+1)=2^k$ means that BOTH $n-1$ and $n+1$ have to be powers of $2$? Isn't it a bit strange that there is no other prime dividing any one of $n-1$ and $n+1$? When can this "strange" situation arise, then?

Can you now take the idea and write a solution rigorously?

Comment: Great! Thank you! My try at formulating this rigorously:

Since the only prime factor of $2^k$ is $2$, this must also hold for $(n - 1)(n + 1)$. It follows that $(n-  1)$ and $(n + 1)$ are both powers of $2$.

We now have two powers of $2$ that only differ by $2$. This only holds for $2^1$ and $2^2$, since even for any other two consecutive numbers $l, l+1$ it holds that $2^l$ and $2^{l+1}$ differ by more than $2$.

Comment: This is nice!!!