# Can four consecutive numbers all be powers of whole numbers?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I need a direction, I was given a hint: the claim is somehow how related to another claim, for 2 consecutive even numbers one is divisible by 4 the other isn't.

Comment: Can three??????

Comment: @barakmanos: the hint cannot be used for three numbers.

Comment: If they are first powers you can have as many as you like.

Comment: @YvesDaoust: That makes the question (about three) more interesting, and the answer to the question (assuming it is "No") more of an obvious hint.

Comment: I realise that you want to _prove_ this particular statement making use of the fact that amongst four consecutive integers there will be one which is 2 (mod 4), but as general background you might find it interesting to know that actually there are not even _two_ consecutive integers other than the trivial ones (0, 1; -1, 0) and (8, 8) for which this holds: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/610131/can-consecutive-integers-be-perfect-powers

Comment: Even _two_ consecutive numbers can't be powers, except for $8,9$. This is because of [Mihăilescu's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan%27s_conjecture).

Comment: $2 = 2^1 , 3=3^1, 4=2^2, 5=5^1$

Comment: @MichaelStocker: much better, $1=2^0,2=2^1,3=3^1,4=2^2$.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Among the four consecutive numbers, one must be of the form $4n+2=2(2n+1)$. As the multiplicity of $2$ in its prime decomposition is $1$, this number cannot be a power.

Comment: However, $2,3,4,5$ works if you count primes as powers of primes.

Comment: @JanDvorak: allowing first powers is of little interest.

Comment: I know Mihăilescu's theorem, but this thread makes me wonder if there is an _elementary_ way to see that the ___three___ consecutive integers $4n-1$, $4n$ and $4n+1$ can never be simultaneously perfect powers. Becuase four consecutive are very easy to rule out, and two consecutive were a tough problem for a long time.